# How to diff against a git branch?

Tags: diff, diff-mode

I'm currently using `(vc-root-diff nil)` however, I'd like to spesify a branch.

Calling `(vc-root-diff t)` prompts for the revision, and the path.

Is there a way to diff against a branch without, manually entering it in every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using:

`(vc-root-version-diff nil "master" nil)`

- The first `nil` could be replaced by `(vc-root-dir)`.
- The second one *could* be replaced by `HEAD` however this doesn't include local changes to the tree, so it needs to be `nil`.